# regex to replace &nbsp; to "" does not work - Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace all `&nbsp;` in a string with "" but the below does not seem to work.

```
str.replace("&nbsp","");
```

My string:

```
<img alt="" src="abc430.jpg" width="650" height="430" /> u seen&nbsp; <a  
href="http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank"></a>&nbsp;hey hey hey

trying to get this output: 
<img alt="" src="abc430.jpg" width="650" height="430" /> u seen <a  
href="http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank"></a>hey hey hey
```

Now the replace code does replace & nbsp; with "" but still my output on the page is

```
u seen 
link here
hey hey
```

It's not in one line

Comment: Is this Java? Or JavaScript?

Comment: define `does not seem to work`. Post actual code reproducing the issue, input, output, expected output.

Comment: why are you using &nbsp . does your string contain string like that / or the intention is just remove spaces ?

Comment: Sidenode: That's not a `regex`. If you wrap it in `"` it will be handled as a string. A Regex would look like `str.replace(/&nbsp/, ""); `

Comment: The code you posted will find the five characters `&`, `n`, `b`, `s`, `p` in order (you might have left out `;`), and when it finds those five characters, it will remove them.  If you need to replace something different, instead of that 5-character or 6-character sequence, you will need to do something different.  Java is not HTML.  Java does not recognize `&nbsp` as anything special.

Comment: @dognose What language are you talking about???  This is tagged Java, not JavaScript or Perl.

Comment: @ajb true. But due to first question, and the fact that "html" would have NOTHING to do with the issue in case of java, i assumed that "java" means "javascript" here (Also java's str.replace() is not related to regex, JavaScripts is!).

Comment: @ajb `relace()` and `replaceAll()` both replace all. Only difference is `relaceAll` takes regex as parameter. It confuses everyone for this weird name.

Comment: @SabujHassan brain fart, fixed my comment.

Comment: @SabujHassan To make it more confusiong: replace also handles RegExps and CAN replace ALL: `str.replace(/test/g, "") == str.replaceAll("test", "")`

Answer (score 4):

It works. You didn't assign the replaced string into `str`

```
str = str.replace("&nbsp;","");
```

Try to run this code from your end:

```
String str = "alex &nbsp; alex";
str = str.replace("&nbsp;","");
System.out.println(str);
```

Outputs:

```
alex  alex
```

Comment: I did it. but it's not replacing it.

Comment: Maybe you should show your full code, then? After all, if you "did it" despite your code sample not showing an assignment, that means you're not giving us an accurate picture of what you have tried.

Comment: This approach will work - I would almost bet that the string you're trying to modify isn't what you think it is, and that the ampersand is being escaped.  That is, you're passing `"some &amp;nbsp; string"` instead of `"some &nbsp; string"`

Comment: @SabujHassan -  It does replace the &nbsp; with "" but in the HTML it still has a space wonder why. The inspect element does not show any &nbsp; though

Comment: @user3298846 are you sure what you are asking? It will be great if you can update your question with some description. If you want to replace  consecutive spaces with single one, try this `str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");`

Comment: hey thanks @sabuj. have edited the post above. pls see